# Excel plugin debugging fails due to error in VS2010

Tags: c#-4.0, plugins, configuration, excel-2010, platform

I am trying to understand a project which is a Excel plugin. Normally, It has to start the debugging in by loading the Excel plugin to the MS Excel application. Here, The project is built correctly but when I run the project, It gives an error as shown below.

System can not find the file specified.It finds the 32 version of the office excel but I have 64 bit version. It is not automatically identified.

[image]

I have no `excel.exe` in this path because my Office Package is `X64`. My existing excel.exe file exists in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe` path.

But the strange thing is that, If I build the project and installed the project, It is installed into the Excel correctly. But the problem is in debugging in visual studio. Is there a way to select between these platforms other than in the `Solution => Properties => Configuration Properties`. I can not understand why this is not taking the path of existing `excel.exe` path. IS there a way to force the project to search for existing office installation?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must follow this procedure to debug a 64 bit plug-in.

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012014.aspx